# How to access my D:\ drive from the Ubuntu command line on Windows 10

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I open the Ubuntu windows store app and the bash command line (if I am not wrong?) comes up it's working directory is /home/username . I want to run a script which on my Windows is located in D:\University... . Can I do this and if so how?

I have only tried cd D:\ but I get " -bash: cd: D:: No such file or directory". I don't have any experience so far with Linux so I don't know if Ubuntu on Windows can only run in its own location or it can access all the files on my PC.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use `mnt` to access your drives.

`root@user-pc: cd /mnt/d/your_destination_directory`;